# jquery activating radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several radio button that look like this:

```
<div id="TheOptions">
  <input type="radio" name="mylist"/>option 1
  <input type="radio" name="mylist"/>option 2
  <input type="radio" name="mylist"/>option 3
  <input type="radio" name="mylist"/>option 4
</div>
```

How do I set option n to be selected?

So far, I have

`$('#TheOptions').find('input:radio').attr('checked', 'checked');`

but I need to write something like

```
function (theindex) { "select option index"; }
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: An aside -- make your "option #" labels into `label`s so they're clickable `<label><input type="radio" name="mylist"/>option 1</label>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [jQuery's eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('#TheOptions').find('input:radio').eq(3).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

or

```
$('#TheOptions').find('input:radio:eq(3)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Yes, thank you: all I did was put my parameter in and it works great.

Comment: you don't need `$('#TheOptions').find('input:radio')` you can just write `$('#TheOptions input:radio')`

Answer (score 3):

```
function SelectIndex(index) 
{ 
    $('#TheOptions input:radio').eq(index).attr('checked', true);
}
```

---

**working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/PFWK5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can access them using an index selector:

```
$('input:radio:eq(0)', '#TheOptions').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Or some people will provide ids on their radios and access them that way.

```
<div id="TheOptions">
  <input type="radio" id="option1" name="mylist"/>option 1
  <input type="radio" id="option2" name="mylist"/>option 2
  <input type="radio" id="option3" name="mylist"/>option 3
  <input type="radio" id="option4" name="mylist"/>option 4
</div>
```

Then they access it like this:

```
$('#option1').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Fair enough, changed to 'some'